# How to enlarge or move bitlocker system partition

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, bitlocker

I have 2 partitions on my 120 GB SSD (one for system, one for multimedia data which rarely changes). I am using Bitlocker encryption for both partition. After I have replaced the SSD with larger one, I wanted to enlarge both partitions, however could not find a way how to do it. Particulary I needed to extend the C drive as it was almost full and prevented further Windows updates installations.

First I cloned the entire disk with HDClone - unfortunately it treats bitlocker paritions as raw data, so can't manipulate them, only copy them block-by-block. So I have ended with my new SSD having two small partitions and after them half of SSD as unassigned space.

I tried various free partitioning tools, but could not find any which would be able to move the D drive. For all the bitlocker partition was raw data. The Windows itself is able to resize bitlocker partitions, but is not able to move them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I was able to find `AOMEI Partition Assistant`, which is able to "copy" bitlocker partition even into the same drive. For D drive this is an online operation and it can "move" the partition to get some free space after the C drive. However it can't resize bitlocker partitions.

Using this I was able to make a free space between C and D drives. Then I used built-in Windows `Disk Management` component of  `Computer Management` to extend both partitions (`Extend Volume` options after right-clicking on partition).

Answer (score 2):

Couse of problem is Bit locker, in Start menu, search for Device encription, turn it off, it would take a long time. After that, you can move data partition as usual.

Comment: Of course I know the "issue" is Bitlocker. But my question was about how to move "D" partition to free space for extending C partition, not how to turn off bitlocker, which would take too much time...

Comment: That fixed my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same situation, except I have only 1 main partition (the OS).  Here's what I did.

(Most of this is just high-level notes, specific steps can be found in this post)

1. Backup current data.
2. Get the BitLocker key for the drive.
3. Download the [gparted live ISO](https://gparted.org/liveusb.php), create a live USB, and configure the computer to boot from it (possibly some BIOS setting change, or Boot menu, maybe even need to disable Secure Boot in the BIOS).
4. Shutdown the computer.
   Be sure Windows properly shuts down before going to the next steps (will save a hassle later).  This is especially applicable when trying to get the computer to boot off the GParted Live USB (and wanting to hit the power button when it skips the USB and is booting Windows).
5. Connect the new disk to the computer.  If the new disk is something like a M.2 SSD and your computer doesn't have any extra slots you can get an adapter that'll connect it to a USB port.
6. Boot into GParted
7. Determine and note down which disk is the "original" and which is "new".  This should be easy to determine by inspecting the disk sizes & partitions in gparted application.  Probably the old is /dev/sda, and the new is either /dev/sdb or /dev/sdc.
8. Close the gparted application.
9. Open a terminal with root privs (right click on the desktop -> Terminals -> terminal with root privileges).
10. Copy the current disk to the new disk with dd.  Assuming the "original" disk is /dev/sda and "new" is /dev/sdb (if not, adjust the following command appropriately), enter the following command in the terminal:

    `# dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb status=progress bs=128M`

    and wait for it to complete. This will copy the original disk to the new disk byte-for-byte.
11. In my case, dd failed a few times with bad sectors.  I used ddrescue then.
12. In my case, I had 2 "Recovery" partitions on the disk: 1 on each side of the main OS partition.
13. Reopen the GParted application, select the "new" disk, and move any partition(s) after the main OS partition to the end of the disk (but preserve their order on the disk).  Once this step is done there should be non-allocated space immediately after the OS partition.
14. Shutdown the computer.
15. Remove the GParted USB and the old disk.
16. Install the new disk in place of the old disk.
17. Restore the BIOS settings as needed to boot from the new disk (ie. boot order, enable Secure Boot).
18. Boot the computer.
19. In my case, during the process of getting the computer to boot into the GParted live USB I shutdown the computer prematurely so Windows on the old disk was in the "not shutdown properly" state.  It seemed like it just needed to boot the first time, which required me to disable Secure Boot (which required the Bitlocker key).  [This page](https://www.repairwin.com/fix-automatic-repair-couldnt-repair-your-pc-srttrail-txt-solved/) has helpful information.
20. Open Disk Management & expand the OS partition.